# Cortar Nombre substr()

Tags: php

Tengo los siguiente nombre  guardados con apellido+nombre en un base de datos `GONZALEZ PEREZ JUAN GABRIEL` en un informe solo quiero mostrar los nombres de ellos. Para Juan seria asi

`JUAN GABRIEL` 
Como lo podria realizar usando el `substr()`?

Comment: Quedan muchas cosas por aclarar en tu pregunta: ¿Todos los nombres tienen dos palabras? Puede haber nombres como `María del Carmen`, o como `Pedro` o como `José Juan de Dios`... Además, si los datos vienen de una base de dados como dices, ¿ **por qué no los traes ya diferenciados en la consulta SQL**, por ejemplo: `SELECT nombre, apellido FROM...`? Así no tienes que complicarte la vida con algo que se antoja *imposible*. Las bases de datos existen precisamente para tener nuestra información organizada y luego no tener que recurrir a triquiñuelas complicadas.

Comment: En la DB guardo los nombres y apellidos en una pura variable `GONZALEZ PEREZ JUAN GABRIEL` de esta forma.

Comment: *En la DB guardo los nombres y apellidos en una pura variable GONZALEZ PEREZ JUAN GABRIEL de esta forma.*... Ese es **precisamente** el motivo de tu error, se llama **diseño erróneo de datos**, que ahora te va a obligar a intentar un código de normalización **totalmente imposible** por lo variable que puede llegar a ser un nombre en cuanto a la cantidad de palabras. La solución es una sola: **rediseñar la base de datos creando dos columnas: `nombre` y `apellidos`**  o hasta tres columnas: `nombre, apellidopaterno, apellidomaterno`.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por tu consejo lo tomare en cuenta a futuro. Agradecido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo quieres hacer con `substr()` para este caso especifico seria asi:

```
$nombre = substr('GONZALEZ PEREZ JUAN GABRIEL', 16, 12);
```

Pero los numeros cambiarian para cada nombre.  Quizas sea mejor en tu caso con `explode` asi:

```
$nombres = explode(" ", "GONZALEX PEREZ JUAN GABRIEL");
$nombre = $nombres[2] . " " . $nombres[3];
```

Por supuesto esto solo funciona si tienes dos apellidos y dos nombres.  Si los nombres no siguen ese formato, tendrias que agregar mas logica.

Answer (score 4):

Al leer [este comentario tuyo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193068/cortar-nombre-substr/193074#comment362341_193068):

> En la DB guardo los nombres y apellidos en una pura variable `GONZALEZ
>   PEREZ JUAN GABRIEL` de esta forma.

Debo decir que la solución a esta pregunta es una sola: **rediseñar urgentemente tu modelo de datos.** El error es ese, porque no puedes usar una sola columna para guardar todo junto el nombre y el apellido.

La dificultad que estás teniendo ahora para querer separar ambos datos es fruto de no haberlos separado al diseñar la base de datos. Es **imposible** crear un algoritmo o función que te diferencie nombre y apellido en tal diseño, porque:

- es imposible saber cuántos palabras tienen todos los nombres y apellidos que van a estar guardados en la base de datos.
- porque hay nombres que parecen apellidos y apellidos que parecen nombres
- porque es imposible saber donde termina el nombre y empieza el apellido
- porque ...
- porque ...

Más adelante habrá otras complicaciones... quiero ver la cara que vas a poner cuando te pidan una lista organizada por el primer apellido, o por el segundo apellido... OMG!!! ¡Y la tabla tiene 10 millones de registros! ¿Cómo hago para normalizarla ahora?  ¿Cómo voy a saber en datos como estos donde termina el nombre y comienza el apellido: `José Martín Pérez` y `José Martín Pérez`  ... resulta que en el primero su nombre es `José Martín`, pero en el segundo su nombre es `José` y sus apellidos son `Martín Perez`... Normalizar cuando hay varios miles de registros ya va a ser complicado.

O cuando te pidan una lista con los apellidos que empiecen con la letra `B`... O cualquier otra cosa que puede ser necesaria en un futuro.

---

### Solución

**Rediseñar los datos para normalizarlos**, creando una o dos columnas para el nombre, y una o dos columnas para los apellidos, según el caso.

- `nombre`
- `primer_apellido`
- `segundo_apellido`  --opcional

Comment: Sera un dolor de cabeza... Hubiera sabido esto antes, nohibiese cometido aquel error (T_T)

Comment: Si todos los nombres siguen el mismo formato, tus ejemplos no son muy buenos.  Por ejemplo para organizar por primer apellido sabemos que siempre va a ser la primera palabra de la cadena.  Tu segundo ejemplo, nunca lo he visto en la vida real, organizar por segundo apellido.  Los apellidos que empiezen con la letra B tambien seria sencillo.  Entiendo tu punto y estoy de acuerdo que el diseño no es el mejor.

Comment: @alanfcm me parece que te equivocas. Si quieres lee la respuesta ahora editada y el ejemplo que pongo de `José Martín Pérez`. En una base de datos con miles o millones de registros puede haber incluso varias personas que tengan por nombre  `Martín` y otras que tengan por apellido `Martín`... tomando en cuenta que una persona puede tener uno, dos, tres o más nombres... **saber dónde termina el nombre y comienza el apellido** es tarea imposible. Para normalizar esa tabla habrá que ir a los documentos de identidad de los 10,000,000 de personas a verificar **uno por uno**.

Comment: Por eso especifique si todos los nombres siguen el mismo formato, es decir que siempre empiezen por el apellido.  En ese caso no importa cuantos nombres o apellidos tenga la persona, sabemos que siempre la primera palabra va a ser el primer apellido que es el mas importante.

Comment: @alanfcm aún así es imposible delimitar. Como bien sabrás, hay apellidos que pueden tener varias palabras: `De Angelo, D'Angelis, Marion Landais, De la Calzada` ... todos esos son un solo apellido.  Eso por una parte y por otra, si tomamos en cuenta los errores que van a cometer los digitadores y otras cosas más...

Comment: Tienes razon, como dije este no es el mejor diseño, sin ir muy lejos lo que pide el OP es imposible.  Sabemos que la mayoria de nombres Hispanos siguen el mismo formato, pero siempre habra casos especiales.

Comment: @A.Cedano Excelente respuesta +1, solucionar los problemas de raíz es sumamente importante, saludos!